# I have two table which have million of records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two table which have million of records. i have a requirement to apply sorting,paging(up to 100 records) and join on these table. Query takes 3-8 sec to  give result .Please suggest better ways to do that

here is my query :

```
; WITH TempResult AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY col1 desc ) AS Row, col12 FROM table1 po WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN table2 PV WITH(NOLOCK)  on po.col2=PV.col3  WHERE   PV.col1 = 70 AND    PV.col4 in(11, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80) AND PV.col5 IN (23) ) SELECT *,4910093 AS TotalRows FROM TempResult WHERE Row >= 1 AND Row <=100
```

Comment: Show us table definitions (and indexes), and your query.

Comment: `suggest better ways to do that` ....better than which one? Show your query?

Comment: paging is apply on this query . every time i need some record i need to run this query . is there any ways to store data in temdb per user

Comment: Add your code etc to your question, instead of as a comment. (I.e. edit.)

Answer (score 0):

Working with what you have provided so far...

Removed `IN` from `PV.col5` and changed to `=`.

Added `BETWEEN` in the second WHERE clause.

```
; WITH TempResult AS (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1 DESC) AS Row, col12 
       FROM table1 po WITH (NOLOCK) 
       INNER JOIN table2 PV WITH(NOLOCK) ON po.col2 = PV.col3  
       WHERE PV.col1 = 70 
       AND PV.col4 IN (11, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80) 
       AND PV.col5 = 23) 
SELECT *, 4910093 AS TotalRows 
FROM TempResult 
WHERE Row BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

Comment: i am using in here because col5 may have multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexing in your tables. The times can go down drastically.

Comment: already have indexed in my table.i have 7 to 8 non-clustered index in my table1 .If same conditions and sorting apply to the table , then i don't want to run that query again. is there any way to store that query's data to table and it last only for that user

Answer (score 0):

I have got 2 points to share with you regarding the below.

1. More indexes may also effect your performance. Please identify and remove the unused indexed from your table.
2. If you use the indexed views then you can store the result set in tempdb and same can be used and retrieved very quickly when user executes the query again.

Please refer to this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/199058/SQL-Server-Indexed-Views-Speed-Up-Your-Select-Quer